# I get rtp stream via VLC but not with gstreamer pipeline

Tags: h.264, gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to get the rtp stream from a DM365 Board.

With VLC there is no problem. Stream can be opened with sdp file.
It is a camera view encoded with TI specific h264 encoder (TIVidenc1 codecName=h264enc) and sound.
I'm developing an application and i want to use gstreamer.
I build a gstreamer pipeline to embedd later video in my app. but I can't open the stream with this pipeline. 
*on ubuntu*
client pipeline

```
gst-launch -v gstrtpbin name=rtpbin latency=200 \
udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264" port=5000 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin. ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! xvimagesink \
udpsrc port=5001 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5005 host=192.168.231.14 sync=false async=false \
udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)8000,encoding-name=(string)PCMA" port=5002 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_1 \
rtpbin. ! rtppcmadepay ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink \
udpsrc port=5003 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1 \
rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5007 host=192.168.231.14 sync=false async=false
```

Sender is DM365 the pipeline is as follow :

**SENDER**

```
gst-launch-0.10     gstrtpbin name=rtpbin 

v4l2src always-copy=FALSE input-src=composite ! queue ! 
TIVidResize contiguousInputFrame=FALSE ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=608,height=384,format=(fourcc)NV12,bitRate=48100' ! 
TIVidenc1 codecName=h264enc engineName=encode contiguousInputFrame=TRUE ! rtph264pay ! queue ! 
rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5000 host=192.168.231.255 ts-offset=0 name=vrtpsink rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5001 host=192.168.231.255 sync=false async=false name=vrtcpsink udpsrc port=5005 

name=vrtpsrc ! 
rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0 alsasrc ! queue ! 
alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! queue ! 

rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5002 host=192.168.231.255 ts-offset=0 name=artpsink rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5003 host=192.168.231.255 sync=false async=false name=artcpsink udpsrc port=5007 name=artpsrc ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it 
One need to tell udp caps information from sender side to the updsrc on client side.
When you generate a pipeline to send video you get caps information from your sender udp element on the terminal.
Just add this to your udpsrc caps="...." and it works.